# Inserting Weekends into Table with only Weekdays MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm needing to insert the weekends into a table that only has weekdays and then assign the last known value to the weekend values. I know I'm going to need an Insert Query, although I'm still pretty new when it comes to VBA and SQL.

Code so far:

```vb
Private Sub btnWeekends_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim db as DataBase
Dim rs as RecordSet
Dim fieldCount as Integer
Dim i as Integer

set db = CurrentDb
set rs = db.OpenRecordSet("Archive", dbOpenDynaset)
fieldCount = db.TableDefs("Archive").Fields.Count

Dim DateVal As Date
DateVal = rs![ValDate]

Do While Not rs.EOF
    i = 0
    Do While IsNull(DLookup("ValDate", "Archive", "ValDate=#" & DateAdd("d", 1, ValDate) & "#")) = True
        rs.AddNew
        ' removed other fields and edited line below
        rs![ValDate] = DateVal
        rs.Update
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'//-----Clean Up
set db = Nothing
set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Data that I have(starting on Friday):

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID |Customer Name|  Nbr |   City   |Value of Day|ExtendedNbr|  ValDate  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|001|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     529    | 91928592  | 1/5/2018  |
|002|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     654    | 85642187  | 1/5/2018  |
|003|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     258    | 78943245  | 1/5/2018  |

|004|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     611    | 91928592  | 1/8/2018  |
|005|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     753    | 85642187  | 1/8/2018  |
|006|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     357    | 78943245  | 1/8/2018  | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
'ValDate then skips past 1/6/2018 and 1/7/2018 to 1/8/2018
```

Data that I'm needing:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID |Customer Name|  Nbr |   City   |Value of Day|ExtendedNbr|  ValDate  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|001|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     529    | 91928592  | 1/5/2018  |
|002|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     654    | 85642187  | 1/5/2018  |
|003|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     258    | 78943245  | 1/5/2018  |

|004|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     529    | 91928592  | 1/6/2018  |
|005|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     654    | 85642187  | 1/6/2018  |
|006|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     258    | 78943245  | 1/6/2018  |

|007|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     529    | 91928592  | 1/7/2018  |
|008|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     654    | 85642187  | 1/7/2018  |
|009|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     258    | 78943245  | 1/7/2018  |

|010|     Cust1   |  91  | New York |     611    | 91928592  | 1/8/2018  |
|011|     Cust2   |  87  | Las Vegas|     753    | 85642187  | 1/8/2018  |
|012|     Cust3   |  45  | Denver   |     357    | 78943245  | 1/8/2018  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
'I'm needing it to add the Saturday(1/6/2018) and Sunday(1/7/2018) before continuing on to 1/8/2018
```

Because there is no `Value of Day` for `1/6/2018` or `1/7/2018`, I'm needing to grab the previous day's values and input them into the newly added weekend dates (ex. 1/6/2018 and 1/7/2018) with the matching information as well (`Customer Name`, `Nbr`, `City`, `ExtendedNbr`).

Thank you in advance for any help/advice you can provide. I'm still new and any chance to learn more is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT1:**

Line `rs.Update` errors with "Run-Time error '3022': The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship..."

**EDIT2:**

The results are input at the end of all the records. Loop is infinite for some reason. The new dates aren't inserted into the table properly (they're all the same dates and not in the correct order).

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. Your first run a loop to add records, then you run an additional INSERT statement to add more records. Perhaps you should take a step back. Add [sample data](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to your post: How does the existing data look like, and what records do you want to insert?

Comment: @Andre Updated post with Sample Data; what I have vs. What I'm needing. Also removed INSERT Statement. For whatever reason I thought I needed to have it in order to insert the data to the fields despite editing the recordset.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems `Customer Name + Nbr + City + ExtendedNbr` identifies a customer, and you need to fill his date range from first to last date. Can one customer have multiple date ranges in that table? Or would these have different  `ExtendedNbr`? Also I assume one date range can span multiple weeks?

Comment: The `Nbr` and `ExtendedNbr` correlate with each other, it's how we identify our customers. One customer can have multiple dates. The table extends to more than a year's worth of data (over 93k rows), one row per customer per date.

Comment: So how would you detect **separate** date ranges? In a worst case scenario, what if Cust1 has range 1 = `2018-01-01 to 2018-01-05`, and range 2 = `2018-01-08 to 2018-01-19`? You'd have to fill 13+14, but not 06+07. -- Or would you just fill all weekends if Friday before and Monday after are set for the same customer?

Comment: The data gets ran and input into a table daily rather than input as a date range. Each date is a new record, I believe. I attempted to open the table as a Recordset to insert new records with the dates needed. The new records, since they don't have a `Value of Day`, will be taking the last known `Value of Day`.

Comment: @Andre I guess to answer your question, I don't want to set date ranges. That would require me to go in and when the weekends are, rather than write the code that checks to see if `1/5/2018 + 1 = 1/6/2018`. And then if it doesn't, input the missing date.

Comment: Is it just fill in all dates that are missing, or just weekends?  What about bank holidays?  Is `ID` a primary key which will also need to be updated - `4` becomes `10` in your example.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook `ID` is just set to auto number. From what I can tell, it doesn't hold any particular value to the customer as we have `Nbr` and `ExtendedNbr` for identification. I'm needing all missing days (including holidays). I figured that if trying to find weekdays, it would also go through and find holidays as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SQL based solution.

This gets all records where for customer x exists records for Friday + the following Monday but not for Saturday.

```sql
SELECT a1.*
FROM Archive a1
INNER JOIN Archive a2 ON (
       (a1.Nbr = a2.Nbr) 
   AND (a1.ExtendedNbr = a2.ExtendedNbr) 
   AND (a1.ValDate + 3 = a2.ValDate) 
   AND (DatePart("w", a1.ValDate) = 6)
  )
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Archive a3 
 WHERE a3.Nbr = a1.Nbr
 AND a3.ValDate = a1.ValDate + 1)
```

and you can use that to insert the Saturdays:

```sql
INSERT INTO Archive ([Customer Name], Nbr, City, [Value of Day], ExtendedNbr, ValDate)
SELECT a1.[Customer Name], a1.Nbr, a1.City, a1.[Value of Day], a1.ExtendedNbr, a1.ValDate + 1
FROM Archive a1
INNER JOIN Archive a2 ON (
       (a1.Nbr = a2.Nbr) 
   AND (a1.ExtendedNbr = a2.ExtendedNbr) 
   AND (a1.ValDate + 3 = a2.ValDate) 
   AND (DatePart("w", a1.ValDate) = 6)
  )
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Archive a3 
 WHERE a3.Nbr = a1.Nbr
 AND a3.ValDate = a1.ValDate + 1)
```

To insert the Sundays, use the same, but replace `+ 1` by `+ 2` in both places.

To insert random single missing days (bank holidays), change `a1.ValDate + 3` to `a1.ValDate + 2`, and remove `AND (DatePart("w", a1.ValDate) = 6)`

**Edit**

An alternate version if `DatePart()` inside JOIN gives trouble:

```sql
INSERT INTO Archive ([Customer Name], Nbr, City, [Value of Day], ExtendedNbr, ValDate)
SELECT a1.[Customer Name], a1.Nbr, a1.City, a1.[Value of Day], a1.ExtendedNbr, a1.ValDate + 1
FROM Archive a1
INNER JOIN Archive a2 ON (
       (a1.Nbr = a2.Nbr) 
   AND (a1.ExtendedNbr = a2.ExtendedNbr) 
   AND (a1.ValDate + 3 = a2.ValDate) 
  )
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Archive a3 
 WHERE a3.Nbr = a1.Nbr
 AND a3.ValDate = a1.ValDate + 1)
AND (DatePart("w", a1.ValDate) = 6)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! However it is giving me a "JOIN expression not supported" error. Searching around, this seems to be caused by the `INNER JOIN` statement not being supported by MS Access. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Both queries work for me in Access 2010. Did you change anything? Nbr and ExtendedNbr are data type Long in my sample table. ValDate is Date/Time. @Symon

Comment: Didn't change a thing. I'm on Access 2007. The query will run, but then give an error message saying it didn't append any values. Did a search on the error and found it may be caused by unique keys, however I have none besides `ID`, which I'm unable to change. Copied and going to re-run. It has to go through 93k records so it's going to take a bit hah.

Comment: I suggest to first run the SELECT query.

Comment: SELECT query ran fine and showed the dates. Although the INSERT query ran and gave the same `JOIN expression not supported` error and then highlighted `(DatePart("w", a1.ValDate) = 6` . Running exactly what you provided

Comment: Check that you don't have NULL values in the `ValDate` column, they may throw the error. You also can safely move that part from the JOIN into the WHERE clause, see edit.

Comment: This worked! I apologize for how long it took, had to run it over night. Thank you so much for the help! Marked as answer!

Comment: I apologize for bringing your attention back to this question- I was wondering if you'd be able to elaborate as to if this will also find all missing dates or just the specific Saturdays, Sundays and Holidays? Ran the code- ran great. However I'm still having missing dates (which are just days the reports weren't ran for whatever reason along with some weekends if those dates happen to be a Friday or a Monday). I can ask a new question if needed, however I feel this still falls under this question.

Comment: `(a1.ValDate + 3 = a2.ValDate)` determines the interval of existing dates that is searched. If you have missing spans of 3 days, change that to `+ 4`, and let the `+ 1` run from +1 to +3 to insert all days between in 3 query runs. @Symon

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

### When entering dates as query criteria, enclose them in pound signs (#)

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Archive SELECT * FROM Archive WHERE ValDate = #" & DateVal & "#"
```

**Edited 1**

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
         If IsNull(DLookup("ValDate", "Archive", "ValDate=#" & DateAdd("d", 1, ValDate) & "#")) = True Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs![ValDate] = DateVal
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: This definitely helped fix my INSERT INTO SELECT query. Although, it still not inserting the values into my table. Adding break points in code, I can see it's skipping my `Do While IsNull(DLookup(DateAdd("d", 1, ValDate), "Archive")) = True` block.

Comment: Just guessing...change dlookup to `DLookup("ValDate", "Archive", "ValDate=#" & DateAdd("d", 1, ValDate) & "#")`

Comment: Added and ran! It now sees `Do While IsNull` Loop. Please see edited post.

Comment: Why all Fields are set with `rs![ValDate]` value. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems like this line is unnecessary `DateVal = rs![ValDate]` and should be removed.

Comment: Re: Edit 3   `ValDate` has unique key constraint & so the error.

Comment: Any tips you'd be able to give to get around this error? I've given it a good search up, but haven't had much success with applying it to my code.

Comment: Three tips  1. avoid adding duplicate value  2.  Use error handling to suppress error  3. Remove the unique key constraint from the field.